# “Show Help Menu” keyboard shortcut & full screen apps in OS X 10.7

Tags: macos, keyboard

if you press `cmd + shift + /` focus moves to the search field in the help menu of the current application. This seems to be broken when the frontmost app is in full screen mode in 10.7.

Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: Many other apps have the same issues (skitch is one I use) so I would guess this gets sorted out in an update at some point. Seems to me that all the shortcuts should work all of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great catch! It's certainly a bug from where I sit.

I filed a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com on this - feel free to do the same if you want it to have more attention!

I can't think of a way to work around it even using something like [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) to try and intercept the key press before it gets ignored.